# How to display data in razor with var value use foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In MVC ASP.NET C#.
I want to view data in razor with contents as shown in the image in following.
link:

[image]

In Controller in have this code:

```
public ActionResult View()
{

  ViewBag.data = db.Contents.OrderByDescending(x=>x.dateCreate).Take(4);

  return View();

}
```

In `View.cshtml` I have code

```
foreach(var item in ViewBag.data)
{
    <h2>@item.Title<h2>
    <p>@item.Content<p>
}
```

It only displays in column.
How to display this as image top?

Comment: What do you mean by image top?

Comment: Please add the rendered HTML for it

Comment: image top in link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zwK5r.png

Comment: You can change your viewmodel to return an image, description and a list of articles

Comment: How to split one articles latest and 3 article old

Answer (score 2):

you parse it in the type which you set from controller and then iterate over it, `Viewbag` is a dynamic object

```
@{
        List<Namespace.Models.Content> contents = ViewBag.data as List<Namespace.Models.Content>
        foreach(var item in contents)
        {
        <div stlye="width:100%;">
        <div style="width:80%;height:20px;">
        <h2>@item.Title<h2>
        </div>
        <div>
        <p>@item.Content<p>
       </div>
       </div>
        }
}
```

Comment: i want to display data with style as image that.
Latest article in left, including: title, image and content
but right is: 3 article older, only display title?

Comment: but i want to disp 1 article at left posion

Answer (score 0):

In view, firstly define random `Content` to show in left side:

```
var contents = (List<Content>)ViewBag.data;

// Select random Content to show in left. Or select you want, not random
Random rnd = new Random();
int cr = rnd.Next(1, contents.Count);
var randomContent_1_of_them = contents[cr-1];
```

With CSS create your style like image, and add to left `randomContent_1_of_them` item. Finally add to right list the rest of contents:

```
foreach(var item in contents)
{
   if(item.Id != randomContent_1_of_them.Id )
   {
     //add here..
   } 
}
```